# javascript object/array for loop to assigns keys

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object that looks like this:

```
var obj = {
    "cat" : [
        {val: 'res', string: "Residential & Single Family Homes"},
        {val: 'Dup', string: "Duplexes & Apartments"},
        {val: 'Con', string: "Condominiums"},
        {val: 'Lot', string: "Lots, Land & Farms"},
        {val: 'Com', string: "Commercial"},
        {val: 'Mob', string: "Mobile Homes"},
    ],
    "bdrms" : [
        {val: "1", string: "1 Bedroom"},
        {val: "2", string: "2 Bedrooms"},
        {val: "3", string: "3 Bedrooms"},
        {val: "4", string: "4 Bedrooms"},
        {val: "5", string: "5 Bedrooms"},
    ],
    "bthrms" : [
        {val: "1", string: "1 Bathroom"},
        {val: "1.1", string: "1 1/2 Bathrooms"},
        {val: "2", string: "2 Bathrooms"},
        {val: "2.1", string: "2 1/2 Bathrooms"},
        {val: "3", string: "3 Bathrooms"},
        {val: "3.1", string: "3 1/2 Bathrooms"},
        {val: "4", string: "4 Bathrooms"},
        {val: "4.1", string: "4 1/2 Bathrooms"},
        {val: "5", string: "5 Bathrooms"},
    ],
    "zip" : [

    ]
};
```

and what i would like to do is dynamically generate an array of zip codes inside "zip" using a for loop. what I have so far isnt working as I am getting a bunch of errors such as unexpected token ect...

im assuming that i am doing this totally wron, but this is what i am attempting to do:

```
"zip" : [
    for(i=43000; i<=45999;){
        {val: i, string: i},
        i++
    };
]
```

Comment: Just as an FYI, you may get some weird behavior with a property named `string`. I believe that's typically a reserved word in JavaScript...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest thing is just to do it after the object initializer:

```
for(i=43000; i<=45999;i++){
    obj.zip.push({val: i, string: i});
}
```

(Note that I moved the `i++`, it has no business being in the body of the loop.) (Also note that unless you have `i` declared somewhere, that was falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).) (And `for` blocks don't have a `;` after them. :-) )

If it were **really important** that it be part of the initializer (which is unlikely), you could use a temporary function you call immediately:

```
"zip" : function() {
    var a = [];
    for(var i=43000; i<=45999;i++){
        a.push({val: i, string: i});
    }
    return a;
}()
```

...but I wouldn't without a good reason. Though I'm not sure why not...

Comment: by "after the object initialize" do you mean outside of var obj = {...}; ?

Comment: for closure +1, even though only use is redability! And it's not a bad practice to initialise this way, so long as each initialisation does not contain any logic a model shouldn't have

Comment: @War10ck no ] should be needed can you elaborate

Comment: @prakharsingh95: He was commenting on an earlier version of the answer that had a typo.

Comment: @DestinationDesigns: Yes. Specifically, *after* it.

Answer (score 2):

Just have an empty array `zip: []` and then use a loop to push objects containing the values into it, making sure you `var` your loop variables:

```
for (var i = 43000; i <= 45999; i++) {
    obj.zip.push({ val: i, string: i });
};
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dbw13m8j/1/)

Answer (score 1):

`"zip" : [       <---- Having a loop inside an array will throw an error
    for(i=43000; i<=45999;){
        {val: i, string: i},
        i++
    };
]`

Supposed to look like

```
"zip": function () { //<--- Need to write up a function
    var arr = [];    // that will return an array instead
    for (var i = 43000; i <= 45999; i++) {
        var oo = {   // 
            val: i,
            string: i
        };
        arr.push(oo);
    };

    return arr;

}()
```

So basically it is a function that computes the array and returns the zip codes.

Answer (score 0):

```
var zip = [];
for (var i = 43000; i <= 45999; i++) {
    zip.push({val: i, string: i});
}
console.log(zip);
```

Will output the zip array containing the objects you desire.

*Edit: Beaten to the punch by Andy!*

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a simple readable solution:

```
"zip": getZipCodes()

function getZipCodes() {
    var codes = [];
    for(var i = 43000; i <= 45999; i++){
        codes.push({val: i, string: i});
    }

    return codes;
};
```

That way you do not modify the object after creation.

Answer (score -2):

You can't run your loop inside of the array literal. This will work:

```
   var obj = {
        "cat" : [
            {val: 'res', string: "Residential & Single Family Homes"},
            {val: 'Dup', string: "Duplexes & Apartments"},
            {val: 'Con', string: "Condominiums"},
            {val: 'Lot', string: "Lots, Land & Farms"},
            {val: 'Com', string: "Commercial"},
            {val: 'Mob', string: "Mobile Homes"},
        ],
        "bdrms" : [
            {val: "1", string: "1 Bedroom"},
            {val: "2", string: "2 Bedrooms"},
            {val: "3", string: "3 Bedrooms"},
            {val: "4", string: "4 Bedrooms"},
            {val: "5", string: "5 Bedrooms"},
        ],
        "bthrms" : [
            {val: "1", string: "1 Bathroom"},
            {val: "1.1", string: "1 1/2 Bathrooms"},
            {val: "2", string: "2 Bathrooms"},
            {val: "2.1", string: "2 1/2 Bathrooms"},
            {val: "3", string: "3 Bathrooms"},
            {val: "3.1", string: "3 1/2 Bathrooms"},
            {val: "4", string: "4 Bathrooms"},
            {val: "4.1", string: "4 1/2 Bathrooms"},
            {val: "5", string: "5 Bathrooms"},
        ],
        "zip" : [

        ]
    },
    zips = obj.zip,
    i,
    counter = 0,
    j;
    for(i=43000; i<=45999; i++){
        zips[counter] = { val: i, string: i };
        counter++
    };
```

Comment: counter = i always. Js engine will auto optimise this, but it's bad for redability

Comment: I agree it would have been better to use push, and I also agree that using "i' for a counter is pretty standard, but I haven't heard the "counter = i always" rule. Do you have a link to any documentation on this that I can read up on?

Comment: @prakharsingh95 `counter = i` is usually true if you're starting with `i = 0`. In this case, though, that doesn't hold true. `counter` should be `0` and `i` should be `43000`. It's not a clean solution by any accounts but this would definitely work

Comment: @dgavian sorry I meant counter is just an offset from i. You are incrementing both when you only need to increment one. you could do zips[counter-43000]

Comment: @War10ck I clarify. If two variables have an unchanging relationship, and mathematically trivial keep only one. For ex, js engine or a compiler will automatically do this, and it's easier to read with one variable.